# How can I contact 'lost and found' to in enquire on a lost laptop in Dubai Airport?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, dubai, dxb

On 16th March 2013, I travelled via Dubai to Dallas. During the security checking at Dubai Airport, I put it in the belt and after that I forgot to to take it back. that I've filled up the online form of Dubai 'lost and found' and got a reference number. but then after there is no response from their side and also tried to call Dubai airport 'lost and found' and Emirates 'lost and found' in Dubai but nobody is picking up the phone. Can anyone please advise how I can get my laptop back.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few steps when it comes to this, and indeed I even overheard airport staff in Calgary yesterday discussing this.

- If it's lost on the plane, then you speak to the airline.  That's the only time it's worth contacting them.
- If it's lost in the airport, you need to deal with the airport.

Now, with regards to them not answering the phone, some steps you could try:

- Try the phone again making sure to call during Dubai business hours
- see if there's an email address on the airport website
- try filling out the [lost and found form](http://www.dubaiairport.com/en/passengers/Pages/LostFound.aspx) again - perhaps it didn't get through the first time
- my favourite method lately - try their twitter account: [Dubai Airports](https://twitter.com/DubaiAirports) - it's amazing how fast airlines and other companies have responded to me when my complaint/query is out there in public on twitter.
- If it was in Terminal 3 - this is one of the rare times that the airline handles it as well - because [Terminal 3 is Emirates-only flights](http://www.dubaiairportguide.com/dubai-airport-luggage/) -  you could call Emirates on +971 4 0505 7584 / 7538.
- Try their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/DubaiAirports) - it's amazing how much faster companies' social media sites reply sometimes.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for the social media pointer.  I have the same experience (although my previous landlord ultimately responded by closing their Facebook account).

Comment: Terminal 3 now has Qantas flights as well.